# Service account client Id : com.google.android.gms.auth.GoogleAuthException: Unknown

Tags: android, google-oauth, google-signin

I'm trying to create a simple Andriod App which allows users to login using Google+ Sign in.

Once signed in, they can access a J2ee server urls. As part of J2ee server logic, i want to validate whether the requests are coming from authenticated and\
riod app.

Based on google help documentation and lot of other blogs, i have created 2 clientds ( under Credentails section in google developer console ).

1. Client ID for Android application
2. Service account

   private static final String scopes = "audience:server:client_id:" + SERVER_CLIENT_ID; // id from Service Account

   String accountName = Plus.AccountApi.getAccountName(mGoogleApiClient);
   Account account = new Account(accountName, GoogleAuthUtil.GOOGLE_ACCOUNT_TYPE);
   String idToken = GoogleAuthUtil.getToken(getApplicationContext(), account, scopes);

I am getting error at the last line ( GoogleAuthUtil.getToken ).

```
com.google.android.gms.auth.GoogleAuthException: Unknown
```

I am not able to proceed further. Am i doing something wrong here??

I see a lot of similar questions on stackoverflow, however most of them seem to their issues fixed. I tried every suggestion. Looks like i am doing somethi\
ng wrong.

Can someone point me in the correct direction.